# Merge column based on condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

How to add a new column value based on condition?Having two data set as follows:
First data set contain 2 columns as follows:

| Start | End |
| --- | --- |
| A | B |
| A | C |
| A | D |
| B | A |
| B | C |
| B | E |
| ---------- | ---------------- |

Second data set contain 3 columns.

| start | End | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 8 |
| A | D | 9 |
| A | E | 10 |
| B | A | 7 |
| B | E | 4 |
| ---------- | ---------------- | ---- |

If the start and end are same, add the time with the first data set.How to merge these two columns in python as follows.

| Start | End | Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 8 |
| A | C | nan |
| A | D | 9 |
| B | A | 7 |
| B | C | nan |
| B | E | 4 |
| ---------- | ---------------- | ---- |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas merge by condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69090245/pandas-merge-by-condition)

Comment: Here,  unique id is not present. Need to merge using the comparision of rows. If start and end of rows are same on both of the data set. Then only need to merge the rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Start':['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
                   'End': ['B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'E']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Start':['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
                   'End': ['B', 'D', 'E', 'A', 'E'],
                   'time':[ 8,  9, 10,  7,  4]})
result = df1.merge(df2, how='left')
```

| Start | End | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 8 |
| A | C | nan |
| A | D | 9 |
| B | A | 7 |
| B | C | nan |
| B | E | 4 |

Here I am assuming that your both dataframe saving same column name as `Start` and `End`